# Deleting namespace boost in c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, namespaces

I am writing c++ in eclipse.  When I add a new class it asks for a namespace.  I added boost because I am using boost.  When I looked at the class eclipse surrounded my class with namespace boost{}.  I thought namespace was for java/c# not a c++. Also, I did a little research and it looks like adding namespace boost is a big no no. So I deleted namespace boost.  One question, is there a good reason why I should of kept namespace boost and will erasing it haunt me later in the dev cycle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Thanks, that what I thought. I don't know why eclipse wants me to add a namespace

Erm. @Aaron, "adding" a namespace is good practice, unless you want to be thrown back into the era of C APIs with eternal clashes library symbols ***or*** clumy `libraryx_myfunction` naming conventions.

In fact, chosing a proper namespace for your classes is so elementary that I'd rephrase that. It's not

> ***adding a namespace*** to your class;

Rather it is

> ***creating a namespace for your to (later) add types and functions to***.

Namespaces serve to separate your code from LibraryX and LibraryX from LibraryY etc. Therefore it is indeed bad practice to chose a namespace name that is likely to collide. Defining user defined types is expressly ***prohibit*** in the `std` namespace (or Undefined Behaviour ensues).

Putting stuff into other lirary's namespaces is asking for trouble with

- future extensions of the library
- internal, undocumented symbols in those libraries
- subtle bugs due to [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) (where the library might start finding your function(s) instead of it's own without knowing)

Answer (score 2):

> A good reason why I should keep namespace boost?

Why? Are you extending the boost library? I don't see any reason to keep namespace boost, in fact, for small projects, you do not need a namespace at all. Namespaces are designed to prevent name conflict, and for a small project, I doubt you'll have any (be careful about `swap` though).

Basically speaking, your question is almost the same as asking why I shouldn't surround my code with `namespace std`, after all, I am using the standard library, right?

Comment: Thanks, that what I thought. I don't know why eclipse wants me to add a namespace.

Comment: @Aaron You don't "add a namespace". You "add a type" to a namespace. Don't start without a namespace! See my answer.